# Show View before displaying thee UITabBar

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitabbarcontroller

I need to display a view before I display a tab based app and once the user taps a button the view goes away.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is some code that demonstrates the process.  You can paste this code into the app delegate to run.  Note, that this is spaghetti code, but I did it this way so you can see all the steps in one place.  Normally, you will put parts of this code into its own view controller and classes.

this is in the appdelegate.. note that this is not completely tested for leaks and stuff.. its meant for an example.

```
@synthesize  tabViewController;


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{


    UIWindow *w = [[UIWindow alloc]initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];;
    self.window = w; //property defined in the .h file
    [w release];


    //create the tab bar controller
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    self.tabViewController = tbc;
    [w addSubview:tbc.view];

    //create the two tabs
    NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    //create the first viewcontroller 
    UIViewController *vca = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    vca.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    vca.title = @"View A";
    [a addObject:vca];
    [vca release];

    //and the second
    UIViewController *vcb = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    vcb.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    vcb.title = @"View B";
    [a addObject:vcb];
    [vcb release];

    //assign the viewcontrollers to the tabcontroller
    tbc.viewControllers=a;

    //release the array now that its retained by the tabcontroller
    [a release];
    [tbc release];  //tabbarcontroller is retained by our property


    UIViewController *vcc = [[UIViewController alloc]init];  //this is the popup view
    vcc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    UIButton *b = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    b.titleLabel.text = @"Click here";
    [b addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonDismiss:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //hook into the buttons event
    b.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 40);  
    [vcc.view addSubview:b]; //add it to the popup view



    [tbc presentModalViewController:vcc animated:YES];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void) buttonDismiss:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.tabViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: do i need to instance the views inside the tab in there (viewA and viewB in your code)? I already have the app built as a tabbar and all the views in it.  I just want to display the one view before the user sees the actual app

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIViewController. Present that controller as a modal view with the tab bar controller. Dismiss the view controller after that to hide it

Comment: ok...where do i do that? where do i make an instance of it? where do i tell it to show? and where do i tell the regular tab with the other views to show when i dismiss the starting view?

Comment: @irco A modal view controller displays *over the top of* your other views. It is capable of dismissing itself so you shouldn't need to worry about the last half of your questions. As far as when to create an instance and show it, you can do that in the `viewDidAppear` method of your view controller. Just `alloc` and `init` a new VC and tell the current VC to present this new one as a modal view controller.